# What's the purpose of raising in error?

Tags: python, error-handling

What's the point of using raise if it exits the program?
Wouldn't it be just as effective to allow the crash to happen?

If I leave out the try-except block, the function crashes when I divide by zero and displays the reason. Or is there some other use that I don't know about?

```
def div(x,y):
    try:
        return(x/y)
    except ZeroDivisionError as problem:
        raise (problem)
```

Comment: You use error handling so that your program will NOT crash when it gets the error. In more complex and important applications, like Microsoft Word or Google Chrome,  if a small error occurs, like the user tries to open a webpage that doesn't exist, the program can tell the user that and let them continue using the program. If the exception was not handled, then the program would crash and close out, which nobody wants.

Answer (score 1):

I your case effect would be the same. But you may want to perform some additional logic in case of error (cleanup etc.) and perhaps raise a different (perhaps custom) error instead of original system low-level one, like with a message "Incorrect data, please check your input". And this can be done catching the error and raising a different one.

Answer (score 1):

There is no point (in this case) in using raise.  Normally, you'd have some code in there to do "something else" - that could include outputting some more debug information, writing some log data out, retrying the operation with a different set of parameters, etc. etc. etc.

I'm not sure there's much value in your case, where when an exception occurs it just re-raises it - it seems like someone (perhaps) intended to write some sort of handling code there, but just never got around to it.

Some great examples of the use cases for exception handling are in the Python Exception Handling Wiki --> http://wiki.python.org/moin/HandlingExceptions

Answer (score 0):

The reason to re-raise an exception is to allow whatever code is calling you the opportunity to handle it after you have done something to handle it yourself. For example, you have closed a file that you were using (because cleanliness is a virtue) but your code cannot continue.

If you are not going to do anything to handle the exception, then no, there is no reason to write an exception handler for it!

The correct way to re-raise an exception is to simply use `raise` without any arguments. This way, whoever catches the exception (or the user of the script, if nobody catches it) gets a correct stack trace that tells where the exception was originally raised.